# Put legends in a given position in a plot

Tags: plotting, legending

If I have the following code:

```
Plot[
 {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}
]
```

How can I modify the code such as the `PlotLegends`, are inside the frame of the plot and put in left side?.

Comment: `PlotLegends -> Placed[{"first", "second"}, Scaled[{0.2, 0.8}]]`; see the Basic Examples in [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Placed`:

```
Plot[
 {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"first", "second"}, {Left, 0.9}]
]
```

[image: plot with legends]

Within `Placed`, `Left` indicates a position within the plot, aligned to its left margin; The 0.9 is a scaled position, at 90% height, the reference being the bottom left corner. Note that if, instead of `Left`, you had used $0$, the legend would be placed "outside" the plot area.

Comment: Marco! Thank you very much!. This works very well. One more thing. In this manner it gets to the left but what If I want it in the left but not as much left?, How could I move it a little bit more to the right compared to where the command `left` place it?

Comment: @John Just like I did with the second position, you can use a number ($]0, 1[$) to position your legend with respect to the plot. As an example, try `... -> Placed[{...}, {0.2, 0.9}]`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you !

Comment: yes! Thank you I have done it !

Comment: @John Thank you. I appreciate the accept.

Comment: MarcoB. Thank YOU. You are the one who is always helping me and other people! You are a life saver.